# Restoring Previous cell value in c# datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to restore the previous value of a cell of a DataGridView. I am currently using the ESC button but I do not want to use it.
How can I achieve this?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
```

If this condition is true, I want to re-assign the previou value of the cell and keep control in cell itself.
The above code is executed on CellValidating event.

Comment: How would you like to achieve that then? After the cell edited with a button? using another key? Please provide more details and some code.

Comment: @etaiso No. In the CellValidating event handler, I want to assign te original value if it is changed to null

Comment: Find the edited query above with a piece of code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
{
     dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
}
```

Comment: Oka! How do I do that?

Comment: In the upper left side of this answer you have a white "V". Just click on it , this way you mark this as the accepted answer (it will become green then).